# FFMpeg Convert AVI to MP4 - Audio / Video Out of Sync

Tags: video, encoding, audio, ffmpeg, mencoder

I have an application that lets users record video from their webcams.  The users record 3 clips, which are then combined into one video for playback.

I am having issues with the audio and video on the third clip sometimes being out of sync after converting to MP4.

Here's how the process works now-

**Combine AVI video files and insert transition videos in between using Mencoder to combine avi files.**

```
mencoder.exe -oac copy -ovc copy -idx -o test.avi c:\temp\*.avi
```

I get this error:

```
Muxer frame buffer cannot allocate memory!

1 duplicate frame(s)! 
1 duplicate frame(s)! 
1 duplicate frame(s)!
1 duplicate frame(s)! 
1 duplicate frame(s)! 
1 duplicate frame(s)!
```

However, the video is combined to avi and this AVI plays back without any audio sync issues.

**Reindex using mencoder**

```
mencoder.exe -idx TEST.AVI
```

The video still plays fine at this point as an AVI.

**Convert the AVI to MP4 using ffmpeg batch file:**

```
set FFMPEG_DATADIR=c:\Presets
ffmpeg.exe -i "test.avi" -s 640x480 -y -strict experimental -acodec aac \
   -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -vpre ipod640 -r 24 \
   -g 48 -b 520000 -threads 64 "out.mp4"
```

This all has to be done programmatically (no video editing GUI software) using command line tools in Windows.

Here are sample avi and mp4 files.  The audio / video sync happens around the 1:03 mark.  AVI doesn't get out of sync, while the mp4 does.

http://trtemp.s3.amazonaws.com/new.avi

http://trtemp.s3.amazonaws.com/new.mp4

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the -copyts ffmpeg option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- I don't find the source composite audio sync to be exactly perfect.  It would be interesting to also see the original three source clips.  A general rule is to always start with the highest quality source possible.
- Can we assume the source three clips also have 48kHz 16-bit stereo audio too?  If there is a conversion going on there then maybe this is an issue.
- FFmpeg's internal aac CODEC is experimental, and that is why you have to have that `-strict experimental` switch.  Since you are having audio sync issues, this is an obvious candidate problem area.  Consider using [libfaac](http://www.audiocoding.com/faac.html) if available.  (You very well may have to build your own FFmpeg compile.)
- Using `-threads 64` is not going to make it go faster no matter how many cores you have.  Follow the generally accepted convention of # cores * 3 / 2.  So, if you have 4 cores, the mast is `4 * 3 / 2 = 6`.  My own experiments with the `-threads` shows diminishing rates of return with each thread over 4-6 which zeros out (*no* benefit whatsoever) over 12-16 threads.  At best, 64 threads will no have no impact.  At worst, it will be slower or degrading the quality of your result.
- Experiment with the `-copyts` option.  *"Copy timestamps from input to output."*
- Experiment with the [`-async`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC12) switch.

> Audio sync method.
>   "Stretches/squeezes" the audio stream
>   to match the timestamps, the parameter
>   is the maximum samples per second by
>   which the audio is changed. -async 1
>   is a special case where only the start
>   of the audio stream is corrected
>   without any later correction.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar audio sync problems with avi or dv --> mp4 with mencoder under linux.
Simple solution was to extract audio first, then convert avi to mp4 and as last step mux both tracks together. could be done with a shellscript avi2mp4.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# convert avi files to mp4 with correct sync of video and audio.
# usage: avi2mp4 <sourcefile> <targetfile>
audiopart=$2.audiotmp.mp3
videopart=$2.videotmp.mp4
mencoder -of rawaudio -oac lavc -lavcopts acodec=mp2:abitrate=128 -ovc copy -o $audiopart $1 
mencoder  -oac mp3lame -ovc x264 -vf yadif=0:harddup -o $videopart  $1 
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -audiofile $audiofile -o $2 $videopart
rm $audiopart
rm $videopart
```